# How to enable a Java application to open files directly. e.g. right-click on a file or directory and being able to click on "open with mytool" 

Tags: java, deployment, operating-system, integration, file-association

I have a general question regarding Java applications and their interaction with the overall OS (Windows, Linux and Mac).

If I have a directory with a certain set of files pertinent to a particular application, is it possible to add a context item to the OS menu which will allow the user to open up those files directly using *my* Java application?

I have been trying to find answers to this but didn't come across anything relevant.

Thanks!

Comment: The answer depends on your OS. But since you didn't supply one, you will probably be using Windows...

Comment: Short answer: no. Long answer: yes, but you have to either rely on an installer generator program or do it by hand for every different OS.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) to deploy the application.  It provides many nice features including registering an interest in a file-type (in the [JNLP](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jnlp/info) launch file).  There is a demo. of this in the [JNLP file API example](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#fs), where the app. registers an interest in ..

> ..file extension `.zzz` (simply a file type unlikely to clash with existing file associations) of content type `text/sleepytime`.

Try the sand-boxed version, which actually prompts the user as to whether or not to make the file association.  In a trusted app., it will simply go ahead & attempt to make it.

You can also control file type assocations in the program using the [`IntegrationService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/IntegrationService.html) (I've had no time to experiment with the service, so there is no demo. yet).

Making a file association using JWS should work on Windows, *nix & OS X.

Comment: Thanks for this, but I am more interested in applications running outside of webstart as well. I think you have  given me a good pointer with the integration service though.

Comment: The integration service can only be used by JWS apps.  ;)

Comment: Hmmm...that's annoying. We also have a web start version, but it's not used nearly as much as the standalone desktop app. Plus most people using the application will probably be offline in any case. I'll start investigations again.

Comment: *"most people using the application will probably be offline in any case"* DYM offline when they are using the app., or using machines with no network connection at all?  I'd find the latter to be unusual, in this day & age.

Comment: Not in science it's not :) If they are out in the middle of nowhere collecting samples, they will have no connection.

Comment: That still does not answer my question.  Is it 1 (offline when using) or 2 (never any connection)?  I ask these questions to give the best advice, if you can't or don't want to answer them, I'll move on to the next question & stop wasting my time.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

Install4j is a commercial product that I use to create cross platform installers for my Java application.  It has the ability to do file associations for different OS.

---

Assuming Windows....

This question is not java specific.  To do this in Windows you need to modify the registry.

A good way to do this is with an installer tool such as [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page)

In you install script, you can modify the registry: [See Ref](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.9.2)

Finally see this article on what registry keys to edit to get this functionality: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-any-application-to-the-desktop-right-click-menu-in-vista/

These keys might changes between different version of windows.

Comment: Thanks. It's interesting you assumed Windows :) I am going for more cross platform. I'd rather not get into modifying registry entries. I already have enough permission problems to overcome on Windows with some users :)